# javascript code is not opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've come across many forum posts regarding opening window as a new tab instead of new window but no use. When I click on a link/something.. at present it is opening in a new window but i want a tab instead of window.

Here is my sample code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myTabs li', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).attr('class') != 'closeIcon') {
        var temp_id = $(this).attr('id');
        selectedId = temp_id.substring(0, temp_id.length - 6);
        $('input:radio[id=all]').prop('checked', true);

        loadAll();
    }
});

function loadAll() {
    var clientForm = document.createElement("form");
    var target = "Map" + (windowCount++);
    clientForm.target = target;
    clientForm.method = "POST"; // or "post" if appropriate
    clientForm.action = "../Test.jsp";

    var idInput = document.createElement("input");
    idInput.type = "hidden";
    idInput.name = "id";
    idInput.value = id;
    clientForm.appendChild(idInput);
    document.body.appendChild(clientForm);

    var nameDisplay = document.createElement("input");
    nameDisplay.type = "hidden";
    nameDisplay.name = "idText";
    nameDisplay.value = idText;
    clientForm.appendChild(nameDisplay);
    document.body.appendChild(clientForm);

    var dateDisplay = document.createElement("input");
    dateDisplay.type = "hidden";
    dateDisplay.name = "dateText";
    dateDisplay.value = dateText;
    clientForm.appendChild(dateDisplay);
    document.body.appendChild(clientForm);

    map = window.open('', target, '_blank');
    map = window.open("", target, "status=0,title=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1");

    if (map) {
        clientForm.submit();
    } else {
        alert('You must allow popups for this map to work.');
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed map = window.open("", target, "status=0,title=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1");
 to map = window.open("", "_newtab");/ map = window.open("", "_blank"); and now both creates tab but creates one extra blank tab. What is the reason?? If I didn't close the blank tab remaining all are getting opened as a tab in chrome/FF but if i close it again it creates a blank window on next click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this line in your code, which specifies width and height of the new window:

```
map = window.open("", target, "status=0, title=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1");
```

When you specify a width and a height the browser will always open in a new window instead of a new tab.

If you specify three parameters, your statement will **always** open a new window, not a new tab.

Your statement should probably read:

```
window.open(<URL>, '_blank');
```

You can find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Position_and_size_features).

Comment: No use.. If I remove height and width the window is in fullscreen but I'm not getting it in a tab. My browser is configured to open in tab only not as window.

Comment: Wow.. It's working now.. Thank You.. But why is it showing one blank tab extra on every click?? I've modified the line of code as map = window.open("", "_blank"); now

Comment: At the same time.. In chrome a new blank tab is getting opened and still my window is opening as window only..